# how do you execute a function on the returned value of another function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

in the following code from Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, the author says we should get an array of length 10 with a value of 10 in each position.  However, I am getting an array of functions--not values.  Why is that?

```
function createFunctions(){
var result = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
result[i] = function(){
  return i;
};

}
return result;  // 
}

console.log(createFunctions());
```

And here is my console readout:

```
[function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}, function (){return i;}]
```

EDIT:  I tried to fix it with the following code, but I am still getting the same console readout:

```
function createFunctions(){
  var result = new Array();

  for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
    result[i] = function(num){
      return function(){
        return num;
      };
    }(i); //
  }
  return result;

}

console.log(createFunctions());
```

Comment: Look at this line: `result[i] = function(){ return i; };`. You are assigning a *function* to the `i`th position in the array. That's why you get an array of *function*s. Why are you surprised about that?

Comment: You have an array of functions, if you want them executed, you need to execute them. I think you mean you want to execute them as you add them to the array, so you'd need to add `()`, although it may or may not do what you expect. Also, `var result = [];` is more canonical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the book, but I believe I found the example you are trying in the book's code, which is available for download from the publisher.

The author is trying to show that a reference to the variable `i` is captured, so executing the functions returns 10 rather than 0 through 9 as expected (since `i` has the value `10` when the loop ends).

Here is the code, with the original `document.write` replace with `console.log`.  As mentioned in the comments, you need to execute the functions in order to see the output described by the author.

```
function createFunctions(){
    var result = new Array();

    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = function(){
            return i;
        };
    }

    return result;
}

var funcs = createFunctions();

//every function outputs 10
for (var i=0; i < funcs.length; i++){
    //document.write(funcs[i]() + "<br />");
    console.log(funcs[i]());
}
```

Comment: fine.  I understand that I need to call the function, and I appreciate what you wrote here.  But aren't I executing the result function when I call createFunctions()?  also, when I put the anonymous function in parentheses as in the edit, isn't that calling the function immediately as well?

Comment: no, in your edit the function called in the for loop is again creating a function and returning it to be stored in the array, and so `createFunctions()` is returning an array of functions.  The difference here is that you are calling the immediately invoked function and passing it the current value of `i`, which is what your functions in the array will return (the value of `i` at that iteration).

Answer (score 1):

it depends on when you want the result there are two ways of doing this

1)

```
function createFunctions(){
   var result = new Array();

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     result[i] = function(){
       return i;
     };  

   }
   return result;  // 
}
```

You would then need to get the return value of the function by calling the function

```
var vals = createFunctions();
for(var i = 0; i > vals.length; i++)
{
    console.log(vals[i]());
}
```

2) Call the function at time of creation

```
function createFunctions(){
   var result = new Array();

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     result[i] = function(){
       return i;
     }();  

   }
   return result;  // 
}

console.log(createFunctions());
```

If you notices I added parenthesize at the end of the function when your going through your loop, doing this will execute the function and return the value.  Without the parenthesize you are simply assigning the function to the to the array not the value